# How can I concatenate multiple MP4 videos with FFMPEG without audio sync issues?

Tags: ffmpeg

My procedure is as follows:

1. convert the videos to 1920x1080 at 60 FPS (some videos had only 30 FPS)
2. save the converted videos in a text file
3. merging the video by an FFMPEG concat

After the videos are merged, the audio is out of sync with the video.

To convert the videos I use the following command: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1 -r 60 output.mp4`
(got it from here: [How can I upscale videos with FFmpeg to a fixed resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63162360/how-can-i-upscale-videos-with-ffmpeg-to-a-fixed-resolution))

My FFMPEG command to concat the videos: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i videolist.txt -c copy final.mp4`

When I concatonate the videos, I sometimes get a lot of these warnings:

```
[mp4 @ 0x55740b62ad40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 336921, current: 336064; changing to 336922. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

A question for the FFMPEG professionals, how can I make sure that video and audio are in sync?

---

**UPDATE:**
Here are the details of the files being listed in the videolist.txt

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 291 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 187 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 91 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '4t6Brqa4E5BnD6vC5inICusEtPtd3nU88NgbmUJ.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:37.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1608 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1532 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cut.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7128 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7576 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 115 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '80SEh7RoTyVPNj3zTZSaixxATvUYXMNyzu15evs.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1191 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1106 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #3:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 70 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'outro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:15.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3417 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3286 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #4:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All attributes must be the same, but your audio has varying channel layouts (stereo & mono) and sample rates (48000 & 44100).

Add `-ar 48000 -ac 2` to your command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1 -r 60 -ar 48000 -ac 2 output.mp4
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid any temporary files you can do everything in one command using the concat filter as shown in [How to concatenate videos in ffmpeg with different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/).